# DirectX not rendering in MDI Child Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, directx-11, mdi, sharpdx

I'm rendering a DirectX 11 scene in C# with sharpdx in multiple forms.
The rendering works as long as the forms have no MdiParent. The moment I set a parent form as their MdiParent they don't show the rendered content anymore and are not refreshed on resizing (see bottom part of the image).

Top part is rendering in multiple form, bottom part same forms with MdiParent set:

[image]

Differences in code in my initialize function:
    `ParentForm.IsMdiContainer = true;` and later on for each child form `MdiParent = ParentForm`

**Initialization of ParentForm**

```
ParentForm = new RenderForm();
ParentForm.IsMdiContainer = true;
ParentForm.Show();
```

**Initialization of MdiChilds**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  ProjectorForm projectorForm = new ProjectorForm(device) {
    ClientSize = new Size(Configuration.Width, Configuration.Height),
    MdiParent = ParentForm,
  };
  projectorForm.Show();
  ProjectorViews.Add(projectorForm);
}
```

The render method runs in one thread and loops through each forms render method.

Comment: MDI is rather tricky and ancient. Why do you want to use MDI? Maybe using `Owner` would work better for you? Or using forms that aren't `TopLevel` (though that's also rather tricky)?

Comment: @Luaan Thanks for your answer, I just played around with the parameters and got it working with `ParentForm.IsMdiContainer = true;` and for each Child `TopLevel = false,` , `Parent = ParentForm` , but no MdiParent set!

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to use `IsMdiContainer` in that case either - you're not using it as an MDI container (unless you have other windows that *are* MDI children). But do note that since the forms aren't top-level, some behaviour is going to change. For example, they will not get activation and deactivation messages, which is a bit annoying :)

Comment: If I don't use `IsMdiContainer=true` the background of the Parent is not refreshed when moving the child windows.. the overall behaviour is really strange.

Comment: That sounds like you took the main form from some SharpDX starter kit or something. Are you using `SetStyle` and/or overriding `OnPaintBackground`/`OnPaint`?

Comment: I'm using [rastertek's](https://rastertekdx.codeplex.com/) tutorials as base and I'm neither using SetStyle nor am I overwriting these methods, is this necessary?

Comment: Oh, did you write your own message loop? Rastertek tutorials are great, but you need to translate them to C#, they're a bit too raw C++ for comfort :) If you're using the tutorial to initialize the loop on the main form, it will disable the normal rendering on the parent. The simplest solution is to just clear the backbuffer every frame. The reason it sort-of works when you enable MDI is that it fills the whole parent client space with a control (`MdiClient`), so the window never actually renders the client area.